# High voltage metallic shield grounding

Tags: grounding, gauge

What size of conductor I have to use to ground the shield of a high voltage cable? I would guess that the size of the grounding conductor is related to the size of the cable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What regulations are you operating under - NEC?  Also, what is 'high voltage' - 220V AC?  10 kV DC? Finally, I've not come across any regulations which specify conductor size by the size of the cable.  Rather, they specify conductor size by current capacity. What is the current capacity of your cable?

Comment: Hi  Kevin Vermeer thanks for your post.  im operating under NEC. For me, high voltage is above 1000V. Im not talking about an specific size. I just need to create a procedure that allows to the engineers to chose the adecuate size of the conductor to ground the shield of the XLPE or EPR cable, according to the conductor size. Thanks

Comment: For all XLPE is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linked_polyethylene

Answer (score 1):

The same gauge of wire used on the voltage wire. You wish safety even if the cable shorts and the power wire is dumped to ground so you need to take as much current as the power wire tags

Answer (score -2):

The size of the cross sectional area of cable shield wire is based on phase to ground fault current and time of clearing of earth fault current. Therefore, the earth fault current needs to be calculated and then by referring to time clearance time of the protective relays. After that by using I2t formula, the minimum cross section can be found.